# Create Route between IGW and prefix list

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-route-table

I need help because I got stuck when adding the route between the destination of com.amazonaws.${AWS::Region}.s3 and target Internet gateway. I can do it in the console but how I do it in my CFN stack I can't figure out
[image: Picture of how I want it]

Comment: Can you share the CloudFormation template?

Comment: I have no one for this. So I need to create a Route and somehow figure out how to write the Properties for AWS::EC2::Route

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53474177/4584564
I follow this example of adding a new Routing table and not using the default one. So I mapped all my public subnets to the route table and added the internet gateway and this solved my issue